# Given frame or code object, how do I get the associated module file loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode, python-module

In a debugger I would like to verify that the source path matches the code that is running. One way to do this in Python 3 is to look at the module byte-compiled file (a `.pyc` or `.pyo`) which has a field for the source size modulo `2**32`.

So now the question is given a frame object how to I find the associated byte-compiled module path. (Again a `.pyc` or `.pyo` file).

```
print(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
```

will get me a source-file name that I can try to convert to the bytecode module name, but nicer would be if there were a more reliable way since clearly Python had to read the module in the first place.

What's the most reliable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the globals (it's the `f_globals` attribute of a frame); it has a wealth of info:

- `__name__` - the module name
- `__file__` - the module filename
- `__cached__` - the `.pyc` bytecode cache filename

Comment: Note. it looks like main programs don't have `__cached__` in `f_globals`.

Comment: @rocky no, Python never produces a bytecode cachefile for the script being run.